# confusion about COV(X,y) calculation in pdf

Tags: statistics

[The question itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOdAp.png)

[The area of pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmt9Y.png)

The pdf function is 6x<sup>2</sup>y for 0<x<1.

In this question I am trying to figure out g - the value of Cov(x,y).

Here are my works:

[For f<sub>x</sub>(x) and f<sub>y</sub>(y)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjV9U.png)

[For E(XY), E(X), and E(Y)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ResN4.png)

Am I mistaking something here?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.